# Add point to shapefile / "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to add to a shapefile a point that is a (x-y) distance away from another point (city). None of the cities in the shapefile have x-y coordinates in the attribute table; I've added them for the latter city alone. To obtain them with the searchCursor I'm using the following code:

```
import arcpy

featureclass = "C:\temp\CITIES.shp"
fields = ["CITY_FIPS","CITY_NAME","x","y"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featureclass,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "17800":
        print ('{1}'.format(row[1]))
```

Which yields the "IndexError: tuple index out of range" for the last line. Am I not referencing "CITY_NAME" with row[1]?

After resolving that, how could I go about adding a new city (point) to the shapefile (using insertCursor)?

Comment: index starts with 0 so: `print ('{0}'.format(row[1]))`. You dont need to add x and y fields, instead use the shape tokens, for example "SHAPE@XY". Or are you saying that the x and y field are the relative postition of the new Point compared to the old one?

Comment: I've tried using "SHAPE@XY" but without success, and I think that's because the shapefile does not have x-y coordinates included in the attribute table. I added x and y fields to the CITIES.shp attribute table, but I only calculated the values for the old city. I've been trying to find a way to use those to insert the new city (i.e. New City should be located at x+0.02 and y-0.03).

Comment: Hi @andm, for the sake of the site's posterity: don't ask more than one question per post. Here, for example, when you ask "After resolving that, how could I go about adding a new city (point) to the shapefile (using insertCursor)?", you're addressing a whole different matter. Such a thing should be in it's own question.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because index starts with 0 and you are using 1 in the format row. Change to:

```
print ('{0}'.format(row[1]))
```

You can then use the insertCursor with the SHAPE@XY token, no need to add x and y fields:

```
import arcpy

fc = 'points'
x_move = 1000
y_move = 500
fields = ["CITY_FIPS","CITY_NAME","SHAPE@XY"]

template_point = list([i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) if i[0]=="17800"][0])
#template Point is now: [u'17800', u'Whatever', (504076.8245000001, 6493719.2324)]

template_point[-1] = (template_point[-1][0]+x_move, template_point[-1][1]+y_move)

icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, fields)
icur.insertRow(template_point)
del icur
```

[image]